# How to access variable of an object in an array?

Tags: java, printf

I am tasked with creating 5 book objects and storing in an array, which I do no problem! I am able to print out the objects' variables using println no problem but when I want be able to move the variable around using printf I dont know how to call upon a specific variable of a certain element of the array. Please Help!

```
public class BookReport {    
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Book[] TheBooks = new Book[5] ;

        TheBooks[0] = new Book("Gone With The Wild", "Paul Mitchell", 1000) ;
        TheBooks[1] = new Book("Harry Toilet", "Donald Trump", 100) ;
        TheBooks[2] = new Book("Huckles Finn Berry", "SpiderMan", 500) ;
        TheBooks[3] = new Book("The Bad Habbit", "Nose Picker", 700) ;
        TheBooks[4] = new Book("Alien", "Mister Green", 600) ;


        System.out.printf("%10s  %20s %18s \n", "Book Title" , "Author", "Pages") ;
        System.out.printf("%s \n", "----------------------------------------------------") ;
        //This works but I cant justify the variables to align!!!
        System.out.println(TheBooks[0]) ;
    }
}
```

```
public class Book {
    private String title = "" ; 
    private String author = "" ;
    private int pages = 0 ;

    public Book(String title, String author, int pages){
        setTitle(title) ;
        setAuthor(author) ;
        setPages(pages) ;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return title ; 
    }
    public String getAuthor(){
        return author ;
    }

    public int getPages(){
        return pages ;
     }

     public void setTitle(String newTitle){
        title = newTitle ;
     }

    public void setAuthor(String newAuthor){
        author = newAuthor ;
    }

    public void setPages(int newPages){
        pages = newPages ;
    }

   public String toString(){
         return title + "       " + author + "        " + pages ;
   }

   public boolean equals(Book anotherBook){
        return ((title.equals(anotherBook.title)) && (author.equals     (anotherBook.author)) && 
            (pages == anotherBook.pages)) ;
   }
}
```

Comment: Instead of relying on `toString`, use your own padding and formatting with `printf`.

Comment: havnt been taught javafx

Comment: @xetrasu Kind of unhelpful.  OP will still have to do the same steps of iterating through the array and calling getters if they use FX.  This is like telling someone who has trouble driving a Ford to get a Ferrari instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the getters for the various fields you want to print:

```
System.out.printf("%10s  %20s %18s \n", "Book Title" , "Author", "Pages");
System.out.printf("%s \n", "----------------------------------------------------") ;
for (Book b : TheBooks) {
    System.out.printf("%10s  %20s %18s \n", b.getTitle(), b.getAuthor(), b.getPages());
}
```

By the way, you named your array of books `TheBooks`, but it is Java convention to not name variables with capital letters as the first letter.  So `theBooks` would work better here.

Comment: This is what I was trying to do. So b is just used to iterate through the books

Comment: @RyanCorry `b` is just a dummy/loop variable.  Read about it in the Java docs.

Comment: This was very helpful! I totally forgot how to call the getters! The only problem i had was that the name values are different so with this for each loop I cant adjust each individual value! I ended up just printing each line individually and they all had there own individual amounts of adjustments!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call specific variable of a certain element of the array. 
you can use

```
java.util.Map
```

for example you can make **Id** for all object you want to store.

```
HashMap<String, Book> h = new HashMap<>(); 
Book book = new Book("Gone With The Wild", "Paul Mitchell", 1000);
h.put(book.getTitle(), book); 
book = new Book("Harry Toilet", "Donald Trump", 100); 
h.put(book.getTitle(), book); 
book = new Book("Huckles Finn Berry", "SpiderMan", 500);
h.put(book.getTitle(), book);
book = new Book("The Bad Habbit", "Nose Picker", 700);
h.put(book.getTitle(), book);
book = new Book("Alien", "Mister Green", 600);
h.put(book.getTitle(), book);

// if you want to call it

Book b = h.get("exampletitle);
```

Comment: I think this is an interesting answer to an entirely different question.

Comment: I havnt been taught that yet. This assignment was in the array chapters

Answer (score 0):

You should also be able to use String.format() in your toString method so that you have a reusable formatted version.

```
@Override
public String toString(){
     return String.format("%10s  %20s %18s \n", title, author, pages);
}
```

P.s. I think it would be good practice to include hashCode() for classes where you include an equals().

Comment: what is hashCode() I havnt been taught that yet

Comment: In that case, you could probably ignore it for this assignment. 

It is a method present on every java.lang.Object that returns a hash code integer useful for hash tables. You will probably learn about it a little later in the course but I'll provide the documentation link anyway if you have free time. It is usually good to get familiar with the java.lang.Object in general

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()